# How to Synchronize iPhone numbers fetched from contacts with the contact names?

Tags: ios, iphone, call, contacts

I am creating one app in which I have to fetch the contacts of the iPhone and call through that application using this.

```
CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
            ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
            CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
            CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

            for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++)
            {
                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

                NSString *firstName = (NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));

                [TempArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName]];

                ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

                for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++)
                {
                    NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);

                    [PhoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
                }
            }
```

I am getting both the numbers and names in different array.But there are some Contact Names with more than one number so the components in Number Array comes more.

Is there anything that can synchronize both number and contacts together?
Is there anything with which we can scan mobile numbers and land line numbers in that list?

Also when fetching the contacts can we fetch the complete name of a friend at once,without using kABPersonFirstNameProperty or kABPersonLastNameProperty and appending?

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to work around some time to get to this done.I had to use **ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex** to get the kind of contact and comparing to both `kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel` and `kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel` and fetching the contacts details in the dictionary form.In this form the numbers are **synchronized** with names.

```
contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (!m_addressbook) {
        NSLog(@"opening address book");
    }

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);

    for (int i=0;i < nPeople;i++) { 
        NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);

        //For username and surname
        ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] forKey:@"name"];

        //For Email ids
        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) > 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0) forKey:@"email"];

        }

        //For Phone number
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
            }
            else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
                break ;
            }

        [contactList addObject:dOfPerson];
    }
    NSLog(@"array is %@",contactList);
    }
```